# How to detect disconnection (RST/FIN) using Windows IOCP?

Tags: windows, sockets, disconnect, iocp

How can I find out whether TCP connection was torn down by the peer (by sending RST packet or similar) using Windows IOCP API? Specifically, I can't send or receive any data -- there's no overlapped operation going on. I just want to get an asynchronous notification. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a read or write pending to detect connection closure. Either will return as Remy suggests on RST but with a pending read you'll also get notification of when the remote side closes the send side of its connection.

I suggest you always keep an overlapped read pending, if you don't want to tie up memory you can always make this a zero byte read.

Comment: Tested. Zero-byte read works. What's even better, it doesn't complete unless there's an connection error, ie. it doesn't lead to busy looping. What's a bit awkward though is that when you want to read some data you have to cancel the zero-byte read and initiate actual read request.

Comment: Then don't use a 0-byte read.  Use an actual read instead, it will just stay pending until data actually arrives or until a failure occurs.

Comment: I meant transition from the state when you are not reading to the state where you are reading. It requires 2 operations (cancel + read) instead of a single one as in BSD sockets. Not a big deal though.

Comment: Personally I would have a normal read pending and simply rely on my state machine to know if I'm expecting data or just connection cancellation notifications. If that's not possible then you could use a zero byte "out of band" read (see http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/10/out-of-band-data-and-overlapped-io.html) which will only return on connection failure OR receipt of OOB data and if you aren't sending any OOB data then you have what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't have normal read operation pending all the time. It would lead to memory exhaustion as it doesn't allow for applying TCP pushback. As for OOB, I see your point. 0-byte non-OOB recv completes anytime when there are any data available. Which would lead to a busy loop when I don't want to read the data. I've tried 0-byte OOB recv and it works as expected -- it ignores the inbound data, but completes on disconnection. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I see your point re TCP pushback and in that situation the OOB recv is probably the best approach.

Comment: Thinking about this a little more, you might want to actually pass a 1 byte buffer rather than a zero byte, I know this will lock a whole page, BUT if you DO get some OOB sent on the connection it will enable you to spot a real disconnect (0 bytes returned) from spurious OOB which you can then ignore.

Answer (score 1):

Your IOCP completion handler will be notified whether a socket operation succeeds or fails.  The parameters tell you which is the case.

If you are using `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`, it will return `FALSE` if any failure occured.  If it was a socket failure, `*lpOverlapped` will be set to the non-NULL pointer value of the `OVERLAPPED` operation that failed.  If `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` itself failed, `*lpOverlapped` will be set to NULL.  If the peer disconnects gracefully, it will return TRUE and set `*lpNumberOfBytes` to 0 instead.

If you are using `WSAgetOverlappedResult()`, it will return FALSE if any failure occurs.  Use `WSAGetLastError()` to determine if it was a socket failure or not.  If the peer disconnects gracefully, it will return TRUE and set `*lpcbTrasfer` to 0 instead.

Comment: Hm. I have no overlapped operation going on. How am I going to be notified about connection failure in such case?

Comment: How are you using IOCP without overlapped operations?  IOCP is designed around overlapping I/O.

Comment: I want to be notified about disconnection even when I am not writing or reading. 0-byte read works well for that, see the answer above.

Comment: you have to use asynchronous I/O for that, not overlapped I/O. You use `WSAAsyncSelect()` or `WSAEventSelect()` to register for `FD_CLOSE` notifications.

Comment: That way you can integrate all the functionality into a single event loop, you need 2 event loops (one for WSAEventSelect another one for GetQueuedCompletionStatus), 2 threads etc. The you need to synchronise the two. Etc.